# Find the top n values in a range while keeping the sum of values in another range under x value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2013

I'd like to accomplish the following task. There are three columns of data.  Column A represents price, where the sum needs to be kept under $100,000.  Column B represents a value.  Column C represents a name tied to columns A & B.

Out of >100 rows of data, I need to find the highest 8 values in column B while keeping the sum of the prices in column A under $100,000.  And then return the 8 names from column C.

Can this be accomplished?

EDIT:

I attempted the Solver solution w/ no luck. 200 rows looks to be the max w/ Solver, and that is what I'm using now. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Create a column called rank RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$200) (used column D -- what is the purpose of this?)
2. Create a column called flag just put in zeroes (used column E)
3. Create 3 total cells total_price (=SUM(A2:A200)), total_value (=SUM(B2:B200)) and total_flag (=(E2:E200))
4. Use solver to minimize total_value (shouldn't this be maximize??)
5. Add constraints -Total_price<=100000 -Total_flag=8 -Flag cells are binary

Using Simplex LP, it simply changes the flags for the first 8 values.  However, the total price for the first 8 values is >$100,000 ($140k).  I've tried changing some options in the Solver Parameters as well as using different solving methods to no avail.  I'd like to post an image of the parameter settings, but don't have enough "reputation".

EDIT #2:

The first 5 rows looks like this, price goes down to ~$6k at the bottom of the table.

```
Price      Value       Name          Rank   Flag
$22,538 42.81905675 Blow, Joe     1      0
$22,427 37.36240932 Doe, Jane     2      0
$17,158 34.12127693 Hall, Cliff   3      0
$16,625 33.97654031 Povich, John  4      0
$15,631 33.58212402 Cow, Holy     5      0
```

Comment: Do you know how you would prioritize the values in column B?  For example if you had the option of keeping the very highest value but then selecting a bunch of low numbers (ex 1,50,51,52,etc) as opposed to being able to select the 2nd through 9th values (2,3,4 etc) while keeping the total below $100,000

Comment: As currently described: sort colB descending, add a running total based on the price in the current row + 7previous rows, then pick the first instance where that sum is <100k.

Comment: I think an issue here is the values may not be sequential depending on if there is a direct link between price and value.  The best solution could be picking values of (1,3,8,12, etc) to (3,4,5,6,...) which your solution wouldn't catch.  The questions seems to be one dealing with combinations of 8 out of 100 which means optimizing from a huge number of possibilities 1.9e11.  I'm not sure how to do it in excel or vba without a bunch of nested loops and a lot of time or solver should work if the number of records is 100 or less.

Comment: @gtwebb - Agreed it could well be more complex, but as stated it's not possible to be sure...

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the solver solution as a starting point.  It involves the creation of some extra columns and total cells.  Note solver is limited in the amount of cells it can handle but will work with 100 anyway.

Create a column called rank `RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$100)`

Create a column called flag just put in zeroes

Create 3 total cells total_price, total_value and total_flag

Use solver to minimize total_value

Add constraints
-Total_price<=100000
-Total_flag=8
-Flag cells are binary

This will flag the rows you want and you can grab the names however you want.